# How can I disable PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST

Tags: android-studio, android

I am working on branding a pre-packaged application, and it has a **contact selector** option that I need to disable since it serves no purpose for us. It's for a single user search using their personal address. I have found an article on how to add it here: http://apiminer.org/doc/guide/components/activities.html

They listed the code as this:

```
private void pickContact() {
    // Create an intent to "pick" a contact, as defined by the content provider URI
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // If the request went well (OK) and the request was PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Perform a query to the contact's content provider for the contact's name
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(data.getData(),
        new String[] {Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { // True if the cursor is not empty
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
            String name = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            // Do something with the selected contact's name...
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to disable this. I can remove the images from the folder that it is calling them from, but that still leaves an active corner. That would be poor usability to just leave it that way. I have tried just commenting and deleting these mentions from the code, and it just throws back 2-3 errors.

This is my HomeActivity.java file that displays the code:

```
package com.votinginfoproject.VotingInformationProject.activities;

import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.votinginfoproject.VotingInformationProject.R;
import com.votinginfoproject.VotingInformationProject.fragments.HomeFragment;
import com.votinginfoproject.VotingInformationProject.models.VIPApp;
import com.votinginfoproject.VotingInformationProject.models.VIPAppContext;
import com.votinginfoproject.VotingInformationProject.models.VoterInfo;


public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements HomeFragment.OnInteractionListener,
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;
    VIPApp app;
    Uri contactUri;
    EditText addressView;
    LoaderManager loaderManager;

    public String getSelectedParty() {
        return selectedParty;
    }

    public void setSelectedParty(String selectedParty) {
        this.selectedParty = selectedParty;
        app.setSelectedParty(selectedParty);
    }

    String selectedParty;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        app = new VIPAppContext((VIPApp) getApplicationContext()).getVIPApp();
        loaderManager = getLoaderManager();
        selectedParty = "";
        contactUri = null;
        addressView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.home_edittext_address);

        // Get analytics tracker (should auto-report)
        app.getTracker(VIPApp.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        //Stop analytics tracking
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        //Get an Analytics tracker to report app starts, uncaught exceptions, etc.
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return id == R.id.action_settings || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onGoButtonPressed(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, VIPTabBarActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onSelectContactButtonPressed(View view) {
        // contact picker intent to return an address; will only show contacts that have an address
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // The user picked a contact.
                // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.
                // Get the URI that points to the selected contact
                contactUri = data.getData();

                // restart loader, if a contact was already selected
                loaderManager.destroyLoader(PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);

                // start async query to get contact info
                loaderManager.initLoader(PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST, null, this);
            } else {
                // PASS (user didn't pick an address)
            }
        }
    }

    public void searchedAddress(VoterInfo voterInfo) {
        // set VoterInfo object on app singleton
        app.setVoterInfo(voterInfo, selectedParty);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        if (contactUri == null) {
            return null;
        }

        String[] projection = { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS };
        return new CursorLoader(this, contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        if (data.getCount() > 0) {
            data.moveToFirst();
            // get result with single column, named data1
            String address = data.getString(0);
            Log.d("HomeActivity", "Got cursor result: " + address);

            // set address found in view
            addressView.setText(address);

            // initate search with new address
            HomeFragment myFragment = (HomeFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.home_fragment);
            myFragment.makeElectionQuery();
        } else {
            Log.e("HomeActivity", "Cursor got no results!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // PASS
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: ... simply hide the contact Button? (set its visibility to GONE) - This is the easiest quick fix I can suggest you other than follow the code and remove or comment out all the unused parts.

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick. I added this to the layout file and it worked like a charm. Again, thanks so much for this simple fix.